# Conditional Statement Within Map Loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

In ReactJS, I am trying to call an if statement within a map loop. An example code is  this:

```
var items = ['abc', '123', 'doe', 'rae', 'me'];
return (
  <div>

       {items.map((item, index) => (
            <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item }}></span>

            {index % 2:
                <h1>Test Output/h1>
            }

        ))}

  </div>
}
```

Except I keep getting his error:

```
 Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected , (73:11)
web_1  | 
web_1  |   71 |                     <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item }}></span>
web_1  |   72 |                     
web_1  | > 73 |                     {index % 2:
web_1  |      |                     ^
```

How can I call an if statement within a loop?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. But you should be able to use either JavaScript Conditional Operator or Logical && Operator.

Comment: Use if() statments also throws an error within the render loop

Comment: [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uxd6Lxkk/) does what you want, except the span + (optinal) h1 are inside another span - probably not what you want - I don't know react very well, but it seems that the result of .map needs to return a single element, not (potentially) two elements

Comment: Perhaps [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uxd6Lxkk/2/) is better, without the extra element

Comment: How is this work index % 2: <h1>Test Output/h1>?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you can't return multiple sibling elements as JSX without a parent container, unless you put them into an array (though you can't return arrays from `render` methods until React adds support for returning fragments).

This is invalid:

```js
return (
  <div>First sibling</div>
  <div>Second sibling</div>
);
```

These are both valid:

```js
return (
  <div>
      <div>First sibling</div>
      <div>Second sibling</div>
  <div>
);

// vs.
// (notice this requires adding keys)

return ([
  <div key={1}>First sibling</div>,
  <div key={2}>Second sibling</div>
]);
```

Second, if you want to use a conditional statement to render components, you have to do it like this:

```js
{(index % 2 === 0) &&
  <div>This will render when index % 2 === 0</div>
}
```

The reason this works is that the `&&` operator in JavaScript evaluates to the second operand (your JSX in this case) if the first operand is truthy. You can also use ternary statements, like this:

```js
{(index % 2 === 0) ?
  <div>This will render when index % 2 === 0</div>
:
  <div>This will render when index % 2 !== 0</div>
}
```

## Putting this all together

```js
var items = ['abc', '123', 'doe', 'rae', 'me'];
return (
  <div>

       {items.map((item, index) => (
            <div>
                <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item }}></span>

                {(index % 2 === 0) &&
                    <h1>Test Output/h1>
                }
            </div>

        ))}

  </div>
}
```

### [Edit] Important note

I should mention that whenever you're rendering an array of elements using something like `items.map(...)`, you should really be assigning a unique key to each element in the list that you're rendering:

```js
{items.map((item, index) => (
  <div key={item.get('id')}>Item #{index}</div>
))}
```

The reason is that React does some optimizations here to make rendering (and re-rendering) lists less costly. If it sees a list that used to be composed of keys `0, 1, 2` and you've done some operation to reorder the items in your state, so that now the keys are passed to your map function in the order `0, 2, 1`, it won't rebuild the DOM to reflect the changed order, but rather will just swap the DOM nodes (which is faster).

This leads to why you don't want to use `index` as a key for your elements, UNLESS you *know* that their order won't change. Let's say you used the iteration index as your keys:

```js
{items.map((item, index) => (
  <div key={index}>Item #{index}</div>
))}
```

Now, if your items change order, they'll be output with the keys in the same order (index `0` will always be the first index, index `1` will always be the second index, and so on) but with different text inside each div. React will do a diff with the real DOM, notice that the value of each div has changed, and rebuild that entire chunk of the DOM from scratch.

This gets even worse if your list elements include something with state that isn't reflected in the DOM, like an `<input>`. In that case, React will rebuild the DOM, but any text the user has input in those fields will remain exactly where it was! Here's an example from **Robin Pokorny** that demonstrates what can go wrong (sourced from [this article](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318)):

https://jsbin.com/wohima/edit?js,output

Comment: so you can return an array of elements?

Comment: @JaromandaX you can indeed, and if you think about it, this is what `items.map(...)` is doing whenever you use it. With one caveat!!! You can't return an array from a component's `render` method (yet). But any other function is allowed to return an array of JSX elements.

Comment: indeed, I did just realise that of course .map is returning an array! The reactjs documentation confused me :p wouldn't https://jsfiddle.net/uxd6Lxkk/2/ be closer to the OP's intent?

Comment: @JaromandaX `null` values won't be rendered by React, so no need to filter them out. However, your example brings up an important issue: if you return an array on each iteration of `.map(...)`, React will complain if you don't assign each element a unique key. If you use `index` for both the `span` and the `h1` (in your example), only the `span` will ever render. React will throw a `flattenChildren` error and flatten the elements with identical keys, throwing out the other one. I may edit the answer to talk more about the importance of keys...

Comment: I'm not using `index` any differently to your code, not sure why you think index has special meaning in my fiddle compared to your answer - maybe flattening the result of `.map` would help? https://jsfiddle.net/uxd6Lxkk/4/

Comment: Err you're right, it's not really your example in particular (not sure why I worded it that way), but just any time you return an array of elements on every iteration like that. In such a case, **if** you assign keys to the elements (which you normally should for performance reasons) and those keys are the iteration index, React will throw out one of the two elements from every iteration (due to an identical key on multiple elements). Hopefully that clears up the confusion, sorry. :-)

Comment: @philraj The real use case in this example is I am getting html content from an api, and then dynamically have to insert content, ie ads, into the html content and then output on the screen. The items are htmo nodes that have been seperated into an array by performing a domWalk along the elements. So the index value represents a line of html, like a p tag, and I am doing things like for every 5 lines, enter dynamic element and therefore optimization is not a goal in this answer.

Comment: @DevinDixon Yeah, in cases where you know a rendered list won't change after the first render you don't have to worry about this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your condition for the if is `index % 2 == 1` which shows the Heading when `index` is an *odd number*

```
{index % 2 == 1 && (
     <h1>Test Output/h1>
)}
```

[Official Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator)

But in your case, you are writing this if condition within {}. That means, you are now writing the JavaScript. So, just use the JavaScript syntax.

```
if(index % 2 == 1){
   return(
    <div>
      <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item }}></span>
      <h1>Test Output/h1>
    </div>);
}
```

*Update:* As  Jaromanda pointed out, you need to return one element. So, wrapping your `<span>` and `<h1>` into `<div>` will gives a single element.

Comment: you need a `:` if you use `?`

Comment: It still get this error: Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected , (73:11)

  71 |            <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item }}></span>
  72 |            
> 73 |            {index % 2 == 0 && (
     |            ^
  74 |           <h1>Test Output/h1>
  75 |      )}

Comment: @DevinDixon I have edited the answer. You need to have `&&` instead of `?`

Comment: I have... it appears using inter brackets {} has issues

Comment: as I said in question comment, return value of `items.map` needs to be a single element, not two